# Mokito JUnit Test is failing when testing with 2 mocked dependencies with one relies on the other?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mocking, mockito

```
Class ToBeTested{

@Autowired
private Repo1Src repo1;// JPA repository

@Autowired
private Repo2Src repo2;// JPA repository

 public Map<String, Object> getAll( long id) {
        List<Repo1Res> repo1Res= repo1.findAll(id);

        List<String> systems = new ArrayList<>(repo1Res.size());
        Map<String, SysSceDto> resultMap= getCorrespondanceSystemSytemDot(repo1Res);

        systems.addAll(resultMap.keySet());
        List<RepoRes2> repo2Res= repo2.findAll(systems,
                id,
                1L);
return new HashMap();
}
}
```

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class ToBeTestedTests{
@Mock
private Repo1Src repo1;

@Mock
private Repo2Src repo2;

@InjectMocks
private ToBeTested toBeTested;

@Test
public void test(){
 List<Repo1Res> lst1= new ArrayList<>();
 List<Repo2Res> lst2= new ArrayList<>();
 List<String> systems = new ArrayList<>();
 generate(lst1, lst2, systems );

 when(repo1.findAll(1)).thenReturn(lst1);
 when(repo2.findAll(systems , 1, 1L)).thenReturn(lst2);
 toBeTested.getAll(1);
}
}
```

I have the Following exception: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnnecessaryStubbingException when i tried to run the test and it's where i call **when(repo2.findAll(systems , 1, 1L)).thenReturn(lst2);**

Stack trace:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnnecessaryStubbingException: 

Unnecessary stubbings detected in test class: ToBeTestedTests
Clean & maintainable test code requires zero unnecessary code.
Following stubbings are unnecessary (click to navigate to relevant line of code):
  1. -> at ToBeTestedTests.test(ToBeTestedTests.java:22)
Please remove unnecessary stubbings or use 'lenient' strictness. More info: javadoc for UnnecessaryStubbingException class.
```

Comment: needs to upload more clear code here and stack trace result? I mean why  generate(lst1, lst2, systems )?

Comment: generate(lst1, lst2, systems ) is just to initialize the lst1, lst2,   systems  varaibles it's a simple list.add function

Comment: i added extra details

Answer (score 1):

Your test is failing because the stubbing of your second repository `repo2` was not invoked during the test.

It seems that the stubbing setup

```
when(repo2.findAll(systems , 1, 1L)).thenReturn(lst2);
```

does not exactly mirror the arguments that your `repo2.findAll()` is called with during test execution. I assume it's the `systems` variable.

As a first fix, you can *open* you stubbing and accept any list:

```
when(repo2.findAll(anyList(), ArgumentMatchers.eq(1), ArgumentMatchers.eq(1L))).thenReturn(lst2);
```

... and then either debug or print the `systems` variable to understand where the difference is.

The failure however is also more or less a *warning* from Mockito as you are stubbing methods that are not used. With recent versions of Mockito, this became more strict and your test fails whenever you stub something that is not used during the test.

You can override the default `STRICTNESS` to either `LENIENT` (aka. I don't care) or `WARN` to at least have warning outputs but no failed tests:

```
@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)
```